# I am unable to import images to my modules on React / Typescript, only require works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

This works without issues at a UI level:

`import profileImg from '../../assets/murdoch.jpg';`

But I get this error on VSCode:

> Cannot find module '../../assets/murdoch.jpg'.ts(2307)

And this works without issues on the UI and also on VSCode:

`const profileImg = require('../../assets/murdoch.jpg');`

But I want to import it because the test is not passing

```
    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

      3 | import ProfilePicture from './ProfilePicture';
      4 |
    > 5 | const profileImg = require('../../assets/murdoch.jpg');
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "jest.config.js", "webpack.config.js"]
}
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

Project tree

[image]

Comment: Show your project tree, what is the image location? `assets` in `src` or in `public`?

Comment: Hi @DennisVash see my screenshot.